# passing model to controller sends null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, controller

I am trying to pass a strongly types my Model from view to Controller. My view is strongly typed. Somehow i am getting "null" in the property values when the "Save" action method is called in the controller. I am using `Asp.Net MVC 3`.

This is how my View looks like:

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Event
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AddNew</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using(Html.BeginForm("Save","Event",FormMethod.Post, Model))
    {
        <div>
            <p>@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.EventName) @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.EventName)</p>
            <p>@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Venue) @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Venue)</p>
            <p>@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.StartTime) @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.StartTime)</p>
            <p>@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.EndTime) @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.EndTime)</p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Save Event", "Save")
        </div>
        }
</body>
</html>
```

This is how my `EventController` looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication2.Models;

namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class EventController : Controller
    {

        public string Save(Event eventModel)
        {
           //Here eventModel.EventName and rest of the properties are null.

            return "Saved";
        }

    }
}
```

This is how Model looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Event
    {
        public string EventName { get; set; }
        public string Venue { get; set; }
        public string StartTime { get; set; }
        public string EndTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionLinks don't submit forms.  Change:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Save Event", "Save")
```

To

```
<input type="submit" value="Save">
```

Additionally, this would have been more pronounced if you added `[HttpPost]` to your method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Save(Event eventModel)
    {
       //Here eventModel.EventName and rest of the properties are null.

        return "Saved";
    }
```

Comment: Is there any Helper method for generating Submit button?

Comment: Nope, however there are probably a ton of examples of creating your own helper to do that.

Answer (score 1):

`ActionLink` helper method renders an anchor tag which is a link. It will not submit the form. You need a submit button in your form as Erik mentioned.

If you still want to keep the link instead of submit button you can use some javascript code to submit the form

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(function(){
      $("#Save").click(function(){
         $(this).closest("form").submit();        
      });
    });

</script>
```